# Should I use inline or #define in this issue?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I work with pthreads and I want to use this code:

```
if(pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)){
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
        return ERROR;
    }
```

my question is should I do it with `#define` or should I do it with inline function:

```
inline void func() {

if(pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)){
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
        return ERROR;
    }

}
```

Should the function be static? such as:

```
static inline void func()
```

Comment: What benefit do you get from `#define`?

Comment: What? By like 10 characters. And if you write it safely then the macro will be longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do anything with macros if you can help it (and here, you can help it).

If your function lives and is used solely in a cpp it should be in an unnamed namespace...

```
namespace
{
    void func(){/*...*/}
}
```

If it's declared in a header and meant to be used from many other cpps it should not be static or in an unnamed namespace.

Comment: +1 just for 'You shouldn't do anything with macros if you can help it'.

Comment: I don't understand at all what the namespace has to do with the question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr He asked if he should use `static`, which in global namespace specifies internal linkage - but that use of static has been replaced by using unnamed namespaces instead.

Answer (score 2):

`inline` is irrelevant. You do realize that you'll have to make the function take as a parameter a reference to whatever type `lock` is, and then allow a return type.

So do something like:

```
ErrorType func(LockType &lock) 
{
     if(pthread_mutex_lock(&lock))
     { 
           prtSysErr(!DIRECT_EXIT,!FATAL); 
           return ERROR; 
     } 
     return NOERROR;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
if(func(lock)==ERROR)
{
     return ERROR;
}
```

I'm calling the type of the lock `LockType` and the type of the error `ErrorType` for you to place in whatever they are.  I'm also assuming the value of no error being called `NOERROR` similarly.

Yeah, and don't call it `func`, and put it in a `namespace` like @Dave said.

Comment: Let's hope `lock` isn't global!

Comment: That's the caller of `func`'s problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ way would be to take the lock in a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) way and to throw an exception from the constructor if locking fails.  See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7977272/104774).

Answer (score 1):

No, You should not use macro.
You can mark it as inline or just use it as a normal function the compiler will inline it if it finds an appropriate candidate for doing so.
Note, that if you mark the function as `static` you can only use it within the Translation Unit where you declare it.

**Why?**

With functions you get type checking of the function arguments being passed you don't get that with macro.
Also, with an macro you are exposed to silly and strange side effects which the macro might produce.